# Shopify: Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am new to shopify learning and wanted to start development on local, I have created a merchant account and test store there, I almost done with setup but on clicking of below button from partner account
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUJZr.png)
facing below error of whitelisting URL
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpFZn.png)

I already whitelisted my localhost url along with ngrok url in whitelisting section and double checked for trailing spaces as well but still not able to run it and facing the same issue, can some one help me for this issue please.
ss for whitelisting urls below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiaUg.png)

I tried some solutions like checking trailing spaces or cross check application secret and key but all are OK from my end.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the problem. edit ouath applications record and add callback_path to `Redirect URI` column.

Follow this guide for more details.

https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/auth/oauth/getting-started